# Reading JLD structures on R

Tags: r, data-structures, julia

I am doing my computations on Julia and I got results stored in JLD files, and I want to know if there is some interface that makes R able to read them. Or is there another file extension cooler for transferring data-structures between R and Julia?

Comment: There are many options. If you use JLD then you can read them as any other HDF5 file, eg. using `rhdf5` package from Bioconductor. You could also directly write HDF5 files using HDF5.jl package. Other option would be to use Feather format (it is less flexible) - there are packages both for Julia and R supporting it.

Comment: A second vote for hdf5. Almost every language has an hdf5 interface so it is a highly portable format

Comment: you could use `RCall` from julia and store them as with `saveRDS`, this will probably not work for any type of object though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, use `rhdf5` to read `.jld` files into R.

The syntax is simply:

```
h5read("path/to/file.jld", "field_name")
```

Comment: What if you don't know the field names? Is there a way to read the entire file into, say, an R list object? Or at the very least, is there a function to acquire the field names?